# Migrating from Legacy SQL: options for "WITHIN RECORD" with Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to migrate to Standard SQL from BigQuery Legacy SQL. The Legacy product offered the ability to query "WITHIN RECORD" which came in handy on  numerous occasions.

I am looking for an efficient alternative to WITHIN RECORD. I could always just use a few subqueries and join them but wondering if there may be a more efficient way using ARRAY + ORDINAL.

**EXAMPLE: Consider the following Standard SQL**

```
WITH
  sessPageVideoPlays AS (
    SELECT fullVisitorId, visitNumber, h.page.pagePath,
        # This would previously use WITHIN RECORD in Legacy SQL:
        ARRAY( SELECT eventInfo.eventAction FROM UNNEST(hits)
               WHERE eventInfo.eventCategory="videoPlay" 
               ORDER BY hitNumber DESC
        )[ORDINAL(1)] AS lastVideoSeen
    FROM
          `proj.ga_sessions`, UNNEST(hits) as h
    GROUP BY fullVisitorId, visitNumber, h.page.pagePath, lastVideoSeen
  )
SELECT 
  pagePath, lastVideoSeen, numOccur  
FROM 
     (SELECT    
        pagePath, lastVideoSeen, count(1) numOccur
      FROM
        sessPageVideoPlays
      GROUP BY
        pagePath, lastVideoSeen
)
```

**Resulting output:**

[image: Table 1]

**Questions:**

1) I would like to see the last video play event on a given page, which is what I used accomplish using WITHIN RECORD but am attempting the ARRAY + ORDINAL approach shown above. However for this to work, I'm thinking the SELECT statement within ARRAY() must get synchronized to the outer record since it is now flattened? Is that accurate?

2) I would also like get a COUNT of DISTINCT videos played on a given page and wondering if more efficient approach would be joining to a separate query OR inserting another inline aggregate function, like done with ARRAY above.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) I would like to see the last video play event on a given page,
>   which is what I used accomplish using WITHIN RECORD but am attempting
>   the ARRAY + ORDINAL approach shown above. However for this to work,
>   I'm thinking the SELECT statement within ARRAY() must get synchronized
>   to the outer record since it is now flattened? Is that accurate?

I think that is correct. With your query the UNNEST(hits) from the inner query would be independent from the outer UNNEST, and is probably not want you wanted.

I think maybe one way to write it is this:

```
WITH
  sessPageVideoPlays AS (
    SELECT fullVisitorId, visitNumber,
        ARRAY(
          SELECT AS STRUCT pagePath, lastVideoSeen FROM (
            SELECT
              page.pagePath,
              eventInfo.eventAction AS lastVideoSeen,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY page.pagePath ORDER BY hitNumber DESC) AS rank
            FROM UNNEST(hits)
            WHERE eventInfo.eventCategory="videoPlay")
          WHERE rank = 1
        ) AS lastVideoSeenOnPage
    FROM
      `proj.ga_sessions`
  )
SELECT 
  pagePath, lastVideoSeen, numOccur  
FROM (
  SELECT
    pagePath, lastVideoSeen, count(1) numOccur
  FROM
    sessPageVideoPlays, UNNEST(lastVideoSeenOnPage)
  GROUP BY
    pagePath, lastVideoSeen
)
```

> 2) I would also like get a COUNT of DISTINCT videos played on a given
>   page and wondering if more efficient approach would be joining to a
>   separate query OR inserting another inline aggregate function, like
>   done with ARRAY above.

I think both are OK, but inserting another inline aggregate function would evaluate them closer together, so it might be a bit easier for the query engine to optimize if there is a chance.

Comment: Many thanks Nhan, your approach with the Row_Number over the partition with Rank worked perfectly!